# Jasmine Unit test case for toggling div tag after check box was checked

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a div tag like this

```
<input type="checkbox" #test [(ngModel)]="checked">

<div *ngIf="checked">
 Test Data
</div>
```

and I'm trying to write unit test case for showing and hiding the div tag.

```
 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestCoponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   component.ngOnInit();
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('Div tag should show and hide', async(() => {
   cnst checkbox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#test')).nativeElement;

   expect(checkbox.checked).toBeFalsy();

   input.click();
   fixture.detectChanges();

   expect(input.checked).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: Updated my post with what I've did so far.. @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane

Comment: Ok-- now you need to check your DIV, this depends on how you're hiding it. If you're adding a className, check for that on the DIV.

Comment: I'm showing the DIV when checked == true.. @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane

Comment: So what do you need help with?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382831/how-to-unit-test-the-checkbox-in-angular2